# Java sort object by list type property

Tags: java, sorting, guava

I have the following objects:

```
public class Shipping {
    String name;
    List<Method> methods;
}

public class Method {
    String serviceType;
    String cost;
}
```

I have:

```
List<Shipping> shippings;
```

I would like to sort the shipping by the method that returned the cheapest cost.

**Example:**

```
shipping: "Josh" with 2 methods: "Premium","5" and "Basic","3"
shopping: "Nash" with 2 methods: "Prem", "7" and "Base","2"
```

**will sort it like this:**

```
shopping: "Nash" with 2 methods: "Base","2" and "Prem", "7"
shopping: "Josh" with 2 methods: "Basic","3" and "Premium","5"
```

I need it to return the method that has the cheapest method cost as the first one, while sorting also the methods to have the cheapest one first.

What's the best way to do it? I am using Java 8 if it has a better solution, and have `guava` library

**EDIT:**
cost is a float number. I need to leave it as String as it's an object that I pass to REST api and wouldn't like client side to parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will assume all the shippings have at least 1 method. So you want the methods of the shippings to be sorted by cost. So let's do that:

```
shippings.forEach(shipping -> {
    shipping.getMethods().sort(Comparator.comparing(Method::getCost));
});
```

Then you want the list of shippings to be sorted by the lowest cost of their methods. The lowest cost is the cost of the first method, since they're now sorted:

```
shippings.sort(Comparator.comparing(shipping -> shipping.getMethods().get(0).getCost()));
```

Note that this assumes that you want the costs to be compared lexicographically. If, as I suspect, the cost is in fact a number, then it should be stored as such in the Method class, and not as a String. So make it an Integer or a BigDecimal, or whatever the appropriate type is.

Comment: yes - cost is a float. but I would rather keep it as String as it's an object that I pass to REST api and wouldn't want client side to parse it. In that case - how do you suggest to write it?

Comment: If it's a float, leave it as a float. Why would the client have to parse a number? By making it a String, you make the client's life **more** difficult: it will have, once again, to transform the string in the JSON into a number. Anyway, if you really want to do it the bad way, then parse the string to a float when comparing. I.e. replace `Comparator.comparing(Method::getCost)` with `Comparator.comparingDouble(method -> Double.parseDouble(method.getCost()))`

Comment: Thanks - the client side just displays it and doesn't it to transform it. it doesn't do any calculations. I read somewhere that rest objects should be served the way that client side doesn't need to edit them again

Comment: Yes. `shipping.getMethods().get(0)` will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Agree with the field needs to be a float.  OP is creating far more problems by making it a string.

Comment: @MadConan this means that client side would need to parse it for each object. I thought that the approach is to make them work less

Comment: @Dejel of course. But you need to define how shipping without any method compare with other shippings. Are they lower, or higher? adapt the comparator code accordingly. You really need to take a step back and try understanding how sorting and comparators work, instead of expecting a ready-made solution that you don't understand.

Comment: @Dejel once again: the client will expect the cost to be a number, since that's what it is. So it will receive the cost as a number, because you store it as a float, which is a number. So he won't have to parse anything: it will get a number, and it wants a number. The parsing will be necessary if you store it as a string, because it will expect a number, and receive a string instead, that it will have to parse to a number.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will rethink about returning a String. as my client would expect a string - to simply display it as it is - it doesn't need to do any calculations on it

Answer (score 1):

You need either a comparator or implement Comparable for Method class like:

```
public class Method implements Comparable<Method> {
    public int compareTo(Method thatMethod) {
        return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(this.cost), Integer.parseInt(thatMethod.getCost()));//if you need name then you could do this.cost.compareTo(thatMethod.getServiceType()); assuming serviceType can never be null 
    }
}
```

And then sort your list like:

```
Collections.sort(methods);
```

Comment: Since strings in java do compare lexicographically, you can also avoid parsing to Integer and use `this.cost.compareTo(other.getCost())`

Comment: @francescoforesti No, lexicographic ordering is not desirable for numbers. Lexicographic means e.g. `9` is greater than `10`.

Comment: @Radiodef You're right! But then, the real problem is that `String` is not the right type for that kind of data..

Comment: Thanks. What if the cost is actually Float?

Comment: And wouldn't it just sort the methods? I need to actually sort the shipping while comparing the methods

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort the `methods` field of each `Shipping` instance in your `shippings` list, then sort the `shippings` list by the first element of each instance's `methods` list:

```
for (Shipping shipping : shippings)
    shipping.methods.sort((m1, m2) -> Integer.compare(m1.cost, m2.cost));

shippings.sort((s1, s2) -> 
  Integer.compare(s1.methods.get(0).cost, s2.methods.get(0).cost));
```

You might have to do a little extra work converting the costs to integers, but the overall idea is the same.

Comment: In my case it's Floats. how can I use it? isn't sort expecting int?

Comment: @Dejel It would just be `Double.compare` instead of `Integer.compare`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define new `Comparator` to define your sort criteria like this:

```
Comparator<Shipping> shippingComparator = new Comparator<Shipping>{
public int compare(Shipping obj1, Shipping obj2) {
    //your rules for comparing Shipping1, Shipping 2 goes here
    //return -1 when obj1 should be before obj2
    //return 1 when obj1 should be after obj2
    //return 0 when obj1 is equal to obj2 and relative position doesnt matter
}
```

Then use this comparator to sort your List:

```
ArrayList<Shipping> shippings;
//populate List
Collections.sort(shippings, shippingComparator );
```

Comment: I didn't get how to write the methods comparison

Comment: `shippingComparator` is for sorting Shipping list. Inside comparator, you will have to iterate over `methods` list, find out minimum cost and then compare this cose with other objects minimum. Base on this comparison return 1,0,-1. For examplie, get minimum cost in Obj 1 and compare it with minimum cost of Obj 2.

Comment: If you want sorting inside `methods` list as well, you can define similar comparator to `shippingComparator` for `Method` type this time and use this comparator sort `methods` list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you read Java's ordering [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).  Your requirements seem to indicate that you want to sort each `Shipping` instance by its `Method`, and somewhere else you want to sort a collection of `Shipping` instances that you want sorted alphabetically, but its not completely clear from what you've written.

In any case, this is straight forward to do once you read the tutorial.  In summary, you can do this with a `Comparator` or by implementing `Comparable`, and simply invoking Collections.sort(...) on your dataset.