# How to keep the N highest values?

Tags: java, max

I'm doing a method that takes the value from a lot of objects with `double getDelay()`. But I need some help because I don't know how to save the 6 higher values. I thought to make a loop and save values in an array but I don't know how to insert a new value and delete the smallest and reordering the array. Any suggestions to save and order the values?

EDIT:
Thanks to all, I forgot to say that I have to save the object (or the name in a String with getName(), I don't care) too. I thought use queues but I don't control them a lot. How can I order it? Because if I use Array.sort I don't know of what objects are this values

Comment: Sounds like you need sorting algorithms (easily google-able and implementable) and then you can just take the last six if you sort in increasing order. Look into ArrayLists as well for resizable arrays.

Comment: @BenKnoble I don't think so. You may just want to store the N highest values and work with them only rather than doing all that work.

Comment: I suppose, but to keep track of checking whether or not all the values retrieved are greater than any of the six stored values so far? Sounds like a lot of if statements to me.

Comment: @BenKnoble you can use a `PriorityQueue` or a `TreeSet<Integer>` to achieve it rather than using lot of `if`s manually.

Comment: Use a PriorityQueue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: Ah nifty. These things sound fun. I've heard but not learned about them yet. Thanks for the pointer @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Arrays.sort(yourArr) and then take the last N entries.

See answer: [Java - Ordering array values from highest to lowest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446225/java-ordering-array-values-from-highest-to-lowest)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please check my edit because I think I can't use Arrays.sort

Answer (score 1):

You can add all values in an `double[] array`.  Then use `Arrays.sort()` like this:

```
Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder()); // this will sort array in descending order
```

Now you can access first 6 elements of this array to get largest 6 values.

**EDIT:** If you want to keep objects as well, you can use `TreeMap<Double,Object>`. Populate it with ids and objects. The elements in `TreeMap` are sorted by key which is Double here.

You can then retreive last 6 elements in `TreeMap` like this:

```
List<Object> highest = new ArrayList<Object>;  
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    Double last = treemap.getLastKey();
    Object objLast = treemap.get(last);
    hightest.put(objLast);
    treemap.remove(last);

}
```

Note: I have used `ArrayList` to store objects with highest `double` if you want to keep both you can instead use `Map` implementation to save both `double` and `Object`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please check my edit because I think I can't use Arrays.sort

Comment: @D3KA You _can_ use Arrays.sort. I've written up an example of how to use it with a custom data type.

Comment: I tried to implement some code's answers of my question but didn't work. I'm a bit lost. My code right now is like this:

    List air = Data.getInstance().getAirportList();
     ListIterator<Airport> loop = air.listIterator();
            while(listaBucle.hasNext()){
               Airport a = listaBucle.next();
                AirportFlights aF = Data.getInstance().getAirportFlights(a);
                double delay = aF.getDelay();
}

I don't know how continue

Comment: If you already have `List` of objects, you can directly define `Comparator` on this `List`. Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30465541/4880258) to see how to define custom `Comparator` for `List`. After sorting you can iterate in for loop to get 6 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You'll actually want to create a `Comparator<MyObject>` and sort an array of `MyObject` directly:

```
Comparator<MyObject> myComparator = (o1, o2) -> {
    o1.getDelay() > o2.getDelay() ? -1 : (o1.getDelay() < o2.getDelay()  ? 1 : 0);
} // Reverse order by getDelay()
MyObject[] stuff;
Arrays.sort(stuff, myComparator);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    doSomething(stuff[i]);
}
```