# Implementing an hierarchical sorted list

Tags: c#

I want to create a hierarchical sorted data structure that would allow me to display their numbered depth as follow:

```
1 List Item 
1.1 List Item
1.1.1 List Item
1.1.2 List Item
1.1.2.1  List Item
1.2.1 List Item
1.2.2 List Item
1.2.3 List Item
2 List Item
2.1 List Item
2.2 List Item
2.2.1 List Item
...
```

I do have created a base class that can hold hierarchical data and this is working fine. But I want the children to be sorted by the Rank so users can reorder the children. The numbering of the items will be generated at runtime, as it doesn't add value to the class.

```
public abstract class HierarchicalData<T> where T:IDescriptiveData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ulong Rank { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<T> ChildItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title; 
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to create the expected behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java sort object by list type property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465353/java-sort-object-by-list-type-property)

Comment: You may want to look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37208/sort-observablecollection-after-added-new-item for sorting the ObservableCollection